# UML: Best way to expose a UML Diagram with Entities, Services

Tags: uml, diagram

Is there a type of UML Diagram to show for instance a Class with its attributes and if for example a service is called show the interaction and the sequence of the service that is going to be executed.

Let's say:

I have a system with its BackEnd and FrontEnd

Taking into consideration that in the diagram the Class of the screen is shown.
If some button is pressed, I would like also to show the sequence of the service is called (the actions that happen behind).

I know that this could be a sequence Diagram but I want to show also some classes.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can create both a class diagram and a sequence diagram. Then you can add the class diagram as diagram frame to the sequence diagram. 
[image]